# React: Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <table> cannot appear as a child of <tr>

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, html-table

I have some nested data, and i populated it in a table. but i got this error:
" cannot appear as a child of "
How can it be solved

```
{projects.map((project, key) => (
  <tbody key={key}>
   <tr><td rowSpan={project.receivers.length + 1}>{key}</td></tr>
       {project.receivers.map((p, key) => (
           <tr key={key}><td>{p.receiverName}</td>
             {p.pages.map((n, k) => ( 
               <table key={k}> 
                 <tbody>
                   <tr><td>{n}</td></tr>
                 </tbody>
               </table> 
              ))}      
              <td>{project.title}</td>
              <td>{project.message}</td>
          </tr>
        ))}
     </tbody>
  ))}
```

Comment: It's a warning, and not an error. The warning says exactly the issue: you are having a `<table>` element as a child of `<tr>` element, which is semantically wrong.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says `<tr><table>...</table></tr>` isn't allowed.

If a table needs to go inside another (which is a sensible data structure so infrequently I've only seen once (dubious) case of it in 25 years) then the `<table>` needs to go inside a `<td>` or `<th>`.

In this case your nested table only has one row and one column, so it makes no sense for it to be a table at all.

Replace:

```
 {p.pages.map((n, k) => ( 
   <table key={k}> 
     <tbody>
       <tr><td>{n}</td></tr>
     </tbody>
   </table> 
  ))}
```

With

```
{p.pages.map((n, k) => <td key={k}>{n}</td>)}
```